# Is there any way to install and run Autodesk Civil3D (2010-2013) or Infrastructure Design Suite under Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: windows, wine, cad, crossover

I've searched over the net for any workaround to install this software. I tried to install it with Winetricks, with Playonlinux, with Crossover Linux, all with no luck.

The program needs DirectX, .NET and VBA dependencies, which can provide over MONO and other packages/ways, but installing them not seems to solve the install problem.

Is there any way to install and use it (without virtual machine) under Ubuntu?

Comment: Is Infrastructure Design Suite an AutoCAD/AutoDesk product too?

Comment: Yes, [Infrastructure Design Suite](http://usa.autodesk.com/autodesk-infrastructure-design-suite/) is a civil-engineering based program pack from Autodesk, which includes Autocad, Autocad MAP, Autocad Civil3D, 3DS Max Design, and so on. It's a powerful software pack, and would be nice if it coud work under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that AutoDesk is part of AutoCAD and similar software suites, you may want look at [the Wine AppDB Entry for AutoCAD stuff](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=86).  Anything labeled "garbage" basically means "Nope, not going to work!".  From what I can tell, the 2012 - 2013 stuff is all "Garbage" rating, and so is most of the stuff going back to at least 2009.  2008's the latest that has a "Silver" rating, which is okay for most things.